Gap in shower caulk
I had some grout and caulk work done in my shower. The installer said there should be some gaps for moisture escape. I have never heard of this but wanted to see if anyone else had this experience.

It sounds like they got the idea from weep holes for bricks/windows.  Water behind showers is not good, so you try to seal the area from water getting behind anything, no weep holes.  Pictures of where the weep holes are would help, shower doors should be the only place.

mission impossible, if you leave gaps water will come in
